# connecting to a webservice by using username and password

Tags: android, web-services

I am new on webservice issue. I want to connect to a webserver by a username and a password. I found some solutions how to connect and get the response but after some trials I was unsuccessful. I am gettin some errors shown below. Here is my code could you please help me?

```
package com.isoft.uploader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UploaderActivity extends Activity 
 {

//ArrayList<Response> WebData= new ArrayList<Response>();
public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
String path="";
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String SERVICEURL = "http://192.168.10.177/androidws/isandroidws.asmx";
final String METHOD_NAME1="OzelVeriAlanlariniGetir";
final String METHOD_NAME="KullaniciGiris";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Enter);
    final EditText username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //request code for Webservice
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //sending the username to the webservice
            request.addProperty("kullaniciAdi",username.getText().toString());
            //sending the password to the webservice
            request.addProperty("password",password.getText().toString());
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            //Putting the request in an envelope
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransport transport = new HttpTransport(SERVICEURL);
            try
            {
                 transport.call("http://tempuri.org/"+METHOD_NAME, envelope);
                 //getting the response from the webservice
                 Boolean response = (Boolean) envelope.getResponse();
                 if(response==true)
                 {
                     openGaleryVideo();
                 }//end of if statement

                 else setContentView(R.layout.main);

            }//end of try 
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }//end of catch

        }//end of onClick method
    });//end of OnclickListener method
}//end of onCreate method

public void openGaleryVideo()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
}//end of openGaleryVideo method

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}//end of getPath method
}//end of main
```

[image]

Comment: Have you declared all your activities in the AndroidManifest.xml?? Also, check your `UploaderActivity.java` - line 63. Looks like there is some problem in the `onClick` method there.

Comment: That's because it's onClick that he's trying to connect to the webservice!

Comment: Yes I dont have any problem with that I think it is about the jar files but I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: @silentw do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the correct version of ksoap2 jar

[ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

- download this jar and add it your classpath

**EDIT**
Now there is an updated ksoap2 JAR

[ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.5/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

try with this

Comment: Sorry but when I tried this the project is not able to find the HttpTransport Class. In addition when I add both of them I am getting 'Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1'

Comment: @answer88 have you tried with `HttpTransportSE` class from that JAR ?

Comment: now it works! thank you so much! but now the openGaleryVideo() method is not working cause if I am getting true I need to start to choose video. However, the screen is not changing :S

Comment: @answer88 happy that i could help you. regarding the new error, better to start a new thread. also mark this as an answer :)